# python - Adding combinations of adjacent rows in a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

This is my first post here and I'm a python beginner - all help is appreciated!

I'm trying to add all combinations of adjacent rows in a numpy matrix. i.e. row 1 + row 2, row 2 + row 3, row 3 + row 4, etc... with output to a list

I will then look for the smallest of these outputs and select that item in the list to be printed

I believe I need to use a for loop of some sort but I really am a novice...

Comment: Please provide an example array, and your expected output. But it sounds like you're looking for [`np.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html)

Comment: You can make use of `np.roll` command. Look for it

Comment: Use `mat = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [3,5,1], [1,8,2]])` and then `mat[0:-1] + mat[1:]` to get adjacent rows' sum. You can choose the next step which is unclear to us

Comment: Apologies for not giving more detail in the question...

Comment: Example array: array([[ -0.6,  -1.6],
       [ -1.6, -0.6], [ 0.6, 1.6]])
So in this example I will need the first row + second row, then second + third. Output like [first+second, second+third,...]

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the length of the array - 1 and add the pairs as you go into a new list. Then, select the one you want.  For example:

```
>>> x = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
>>> print [x[i] + x[i+1] for i in range(len(x)-1)]
 [array([5, 7, 9]), array([11, 13, 15])]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for! Is there a way to alter this to select the only the first item in each row for the addition?

Comment: Sure - just select the 0'th index in the list comprehension: `[x[i][0] + x[i+1][0] for i in range(len(x)-1)]`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this

```
import numpy as np 
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                [4, 5, 6],
                [7 , 8, 9]])
```

You can first calculate the sum of each row by using `np.sum(arr, axis=1)` the argument `axis=1` allows to sum each column entries for each line.

In this case, `sums = np.sum(arr, axis=1) = array([ 6, 15, 24])`.

Then you can iterate over this tab to add the different sums :

```
lst_sums = []
for s in range(len(sums)-1) :
    lst_sums.append(sums[i]+sums[i+1])
```

Then you can `sorted` or getting the `np.min(sums)`

If you need more details you can look at [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html) function docs, same for the [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)